# What would be the truth table for the following inputs with a positive edge triggered D flip flop?

Tags: flipflop

This is what I got, but I'm guessing I did something wrong:

```
C   D   Q   Q’
0   0   ?   ?
1   0   0   1
0   0   0   1
0   1   0   1
1   1   1   0
0   1   1   0
1   1   1   0
0   1   1   0
0   0   1   0
1   0   0   1
0   0   0   1
1   0   0   1
0   0   0   1
1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1
1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1
0   1   0   1
0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing a D flip-flip with a T or JK flip-flop, which can toggle their output.  A [D flip-flip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop) simply copies the input D to the output on the rising edge of the clock.

The truth table for a D flip-flop is simply:

```
   C    D    Q     Q'
  ===================
   0    0    0     0
   0    1    0     0
   0    0    1     1
   0    1    1     1
   1    0    0     0
   1    0    1     0
   1    1    0     1
   1    1    1     1
```

If the clock stays static, nothing happens (Q' stays the same).  If the clock receives a rising edge (or a falling edge if it is a negative-edge FF), the output  Q' takes on the value of D, *regardless of the current state Q.*

Since there are three input columns (C, D and Q), the number of rows in the table are 2³ or 8.

Comment: I've seen this truth table before, but wasn't sure how to implement it with the sequence of data above.  I tried simulating it in a D flip-flop circuit and those are the values I got, which didn't seem right.

Comment: What I'm asking is - the order does matter, right?  I think that's how a flip flop works, doesn't it?  Thank you for taking your time in responding to my question.  I'll make yours chosen answer since it answered the original question, for the most part.  Still not clear how to fill in the original truth table though.

Comment: @PeterGriffin Well first of all, you have a lot of redundancies in your table -- as I pointed out, three columns should imply eight rows.  Secondly, you just plain have a lot of errors, for example  C=1, D=1, Q=1, Q'=0 -- this indicates Q gets toggled with D=1, and I pointed out in my answer that's not so.